# Why is LINENO inconsistent after multiline piped commands?

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

Line numbers generated when executing the following script with bash (5.1.0) are unexpected:

```
trap 'echo $LINENO' DEBUG

:
(:) | 
# Add any number of lines here
:
:
```

This returns 3 - 6 - 5, while I expected to get 3 - 6 - 7.

The issue appears only when the pipe contains at least one sub-shell (created with `(` `)`) before the last command.

The last command may span any number of lines, they are not taken into account.

The following variations of the script behave *as expected*:

- No sub-shell (3 - 4 - 6 - 7):

  ```
  trap 'echo $LINENO' DEBUG

  :
  : | 
  # Add any number of lines here
  :
  :
  ```
- last piped command stays on the same line (3 - 4 - 5):

  ```
  trap 'echo $LINENO' DEBUG

  :
  (:) | :
  :
  ```
- sub-shell only on the last piped command (3 - 4 - 8):

  ```
  trap 'echo $LINENO' DEBUG

  :
  : | (
  :
  )
  :
  ```

Comment: FYI this changed somewhere between bash 3 and 5, as it produces the expected result on a Mac with 3.2.57.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting point.

I test several versiosn of bash, and found out that the "regression" was introduced somewhere between 4.4.23 and 5.0.0:

$ docker run -it -v "$(pwd)/test.sh":/tmp/test.sh bash:4.4.23 bash /tmp/test.sh
3
6
7

... 5.0.0 ...
3
6
5

Comment: Have you checked the bash bug list?

Comment: That's what I'm doing now :-)

Comment: Doesn't seem there is already a bug report for this. I'll try to submit one. http://savannah.gnu.org/search/?Search=Search&words=lineno&type_of_search=support&only_group_id=811&exact=1&max_rows=25#options

Comment: Here it is: http://savannah.gnu.org/support/index.php?110714

Answer (score 1):

Following the interesting comment from @Barmar, I tested with several versions of bash. By bisecting I could find out the change of behavior appeared between **4.4.23** and **5.0.0**:

```bash
$ docker run -it -v "$(pwd)/test.sh":/tmp/test.sh bash:4.4.23 bash /tmp/test.sh
3
6
7
$ docker run -it -v "$(pwd)/test.sh":/tmp/test.sh bash:5.0.0 bash /tmp/test.sh
3
6
5
```

This has been reported as an issue in the bash bug list:
https://savannah.gnu.org/support/?110714